Uptime check validation and monitoring in GCP network load balancer
One of the critical components in our setup is a regional internal proxy Network Load Balancer that handles the communication between our application servers and the backend services. The challenge I'm facing is setting up effective monitoring and alerting for the uptime of this regional internal proxy Network Load Balancer.
Problem statement: I need to continuously monitor the availability and responsiveness of the regional internal proxy Network Load Balancer to detect any issues before they impact our users. When the load balancer becomes unavailable or unresponsive, I want to receive timely notifications so that I can investigate and resolve the problem quickly. Kind of alerting mechanism.
Based on the information available in the Google Cloud console, it seems I can create an Uptime Check that monitors the TCP connectivity to the internal IP address of the load balancer. However, I'm unsure if this is the optimal approach, as the load balancer is not associated with a specific Kubernetes service.
I would appreciate any suggestions or best practices from the team on how to effectively monitor the uptime and health of our regional internal proxy Network Load Balancer.
Your input and guidance would be invaluable in helping me set up a robust and comprehensive monitoring solution for our regional internal proxy Network Load Balancer. This would ensure we can proactively address any issues and maintain the reliability of our application infrastructure.
